# Unity MlAgents my model jumps unnecessarily

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

I am new to using Unity and ML-Agents. I have created an environment for my model and started training it there. However, my model keeps jumping at every moment in the script, even when it is not necessary. I have given negative feedback to prevent it from jumping unnecessarily, but it keeps jumping. How can I fix this?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

public class MovetoGoal : Agent
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform targetTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform restart;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float JumpPower = 0.1f;
    private bool isGrounded = true;
    private float previousDistanceToPlayer;
    private float totalReward;
    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        transform.position = restart.transform.position;
    }
    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.localPosition);
        sensor.AddObservation(targetTransform.localPosition);
        sensor.AddObservation(rb.velocity);
    }
    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        float moveX = actions.ContinuousActions[0];
        int jump = actions.DiscreteActions[0];
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveX * 8f, rb.velocity.y);
        if (jump != 0 && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpPower);
            isGrounded = false;
            SetReward(-100f);
            totalReward = totalReward - 1f;
        }
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, targetTransform.position);

        // If the agent gets too far away from the player, give a negative reward
        if (distanceToPlayer >= previousDistanceToPlayer)
        {
            SetReward(-0.1f);
            totalReward = totalReward - 0.1f;       
        }

        // If the agent gets closer to the player, give a positive reward
        if (distanceToPlayer < previousDistanceToPlayer)
        {
            SetReward(0.1f);
            totalReward = totalReward + 0.1f;
        }

        // Update the previous distance to the player for the next time step
        previousDistanceToPlayer = distanceToPlayer;
    }
    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut)
    {
        ActionSegment<float> continousActions = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;
        continousActions[0] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Goal")
        {
            //Debug.Log(totalReward);
            SetReward(+1f);
            totalReward = totalReward + 1f;
            EndEpisode();
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            //Debug.Log(totalReward);
            SetReward(-1f);
            totalReward = totalReward - 1f;
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is model script. Can I make any improvements?